# How to enter values that is in my database and display the whole row and its field using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have a database with these fields (MovieName, Director, Location, ReleaseYear, Rating, Genre, Description). I want to enter a movie name like "squid games" and want to get the whole field of data associated with squid games in my database. Also is there a way to enter a genre like "Comedy" and display all the MovieNames associated with the Genre field with the value "Comedy. This is my code so far (I am using SQLite3 and Python Tkinter):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
import os
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("netflix.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Login App")
root.geometry("414x896")
root.configure(background ='light blue')
padd=20

TVType=StringVar()
MovieName=StringVar()
Director=StringVar()
Location=StringVar()
ReleaseYear = IntVar()
Rating=StringVar()
Genre=StringVar()
Description=StringVar()

#Get user input
print ('Search for a Movie')
print ('')
print ('You can search by Name, DOB, Movement or Description')
print ('')


label_1 = Label(root, text="Movie Name",
           width=20,font=("bold", 10))

label_1.place(x=0,y=130)

entry_1 = Entry(root,textvar=MovieName)
entry_1.place(x=120,y=130)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Director",
           width=20,font=("bold", 10))

label_1.place(x=0,y=180)

entry_1 = Entry(root,textvar=Director)
entry_1.place(x=120,y=180)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Genre",
           width=20,font=("bold", 10))

label_2.place(x=0,y=230)

entry_2 = Entry(root,textvar=Genre)
entry_2.place(x=120,y=230)

label_3 = Label(root, text="ReleaseYear",
           width=20,font=("bold", 10))

label_3.place(x=0,y=270)

entry_4 = Entry(root,textvar=ReleaseYear)
entry_4.place(x=120,y=270)


sqlite3 = ("select * from netflix_titles where MovieName like (?) or Director like (?) or ReleaseYear like (?) or Genre like (?)")
values = (MovieName, Director, ReleaseYear, Genre)
cursor.execute(sqlite3, values)
result = cursor.fetchall() 

for r in result:

   label = tk.Label(root,
   text = r,
   height =5,
   width = 414)

   label.pack()
```

I found a solution for my first question to display the fields associated with what I input for the movie name however it doesn't work for Tkinter:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("netflix.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()



#Get user input
print ('Search for a Movie')
print ('')
print ('You can search by Name, DOB, Movement or Description')
print ('')
MovieName = input("Enter Movie Name: ")
Director = input("Enter Director: ")
Location = input("Enter Location: ")
ReleaseYear = input ("Enter Description: ")
Rating = input ("Enter Rating:")
Genre = input ("Enter Genre:")
Description = input ("Enter Description")
sql = ("select * from netflix_titles where MovieName like (?) or Director like (?) or  Location like (?) or ReleaseYear like (?) or Rating like (?) or Genre like (?) or  Description like (?)")
values = (MovieName, Director, Location, ReleaseYear, Rating, Genre, Description)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

1. how to show just the "values" when entered moviename "squid games" for example using Tkinter
2. is there a way to enter the genre e.g "comedy"  and get all the MovieName that have the field genre "comedy"

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't work for Tkinter"*?  Any error shown?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/gia/Desktop/movie algorithm/Database/databaseInterface.py", line 95, in movie_screen
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.



this was the error I have

Comment: The error clearly tells you that the type of the variables in `values` are not supported because they are `StringVar`.  Use, for example, `MovieName.get()` instead of `MovieName`.  Same for other variables.